# Serialize int with xml node name in go

Tags: xml, go

I'm just in the process of learning me some go, but im having trouble controlling XML serialization

I want to serialize an int to `<number>1</number>`, i have tried the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)
type number struct {
    Number int64
}

func main() {
    out, _ := xml.Marshal(number{2})
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

(https://play.golang.org/p/Ac-p1q3ytZ)

but I get `<number><Number>2</Number></number>` which is double wrapped due to the struct its in. If I just serialize an int I get `<int>2</int>` which is not named correctly.

Is there a way to tell the serialize not to render the root node, or to put a property directly into the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As per the documentation for [`xml.Marshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal), you can use the tag `",chardata"`.

```
type number struct {
    Number int64 `xml:",chardata"`
}
```

This outputs `<number>2</number>`, as seen at https://play.golang.org/p/Aoqfs04OTx